# What is the anime film called?

Tags: ultimate-teacher

I watched this anime film when I was young and would really like to watch it again, I will give you as much detail of the film as possible.

1. The main character was a school girl who for some reason who really strong if she wore certain knickers (Not a hentai haha)
2. It is set in a high school which was overrun by the students until the school hired a new principle who was really strong, he had a fight with the student and beat them all
3. The main character had long blue hair, her bestfriend was a guy and her knickers were blue
4. The principle was the villain, he ate fish bones, black hair and very big. When you first see him in the film, I think he is at the bus stop eating fish bones wearing a big coat and hat
5. One of the scenes, the main characters bestfriend tries to fight the principle with a stick, he keeps hitting the stick at his pants (apparently the principle is stronger with these certain pants too, again not hentai) but for some reason everytime he hit one off, another one was there so he kept on doing it until there was a mountain of pants haha
6. I watched this on video and before the year 2000, it was aged 15 or 18 but im sure 15
7. I remember the main character was on the front of the case
8. Another scene is when the principle enters a room and all the students try to ambush him but the principle beats them all
9. The principle dies by falling off a lift fighting against the main character

That is all i can remember, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 6):

This is the 1988 OAV "[Ultimate Teacher](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=727)".

[image]

> **Plot Summary:** At a run down school the "Ultimate Teacher" Ganpachi is sent to get things back on track and prepare the delinquent
>   students for the real world. But the students don't want Ganpachi
>   ruining the gang they got going so their boss, Hinako, fights back
>   Ganpachi aided by her secret power...her lucky kitty underwear. Things
>   get more interesting when we find out Ganpachi is the result of
>   genetic experiments.

Super weird anime as only the 80's could produce. You can find the whole thing on YouTube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mF5NHl0ydT0).

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH!!!!, ive been looking for this film for months and you finally helped me find it :D

Comment: @madtitan - Glad to be of help! When I first read your summary I knew I had seen the same movie, but couldn't remember it's name. Took a bit of surfing to jog my memory. Please don't forget to accept this answer.